# How do I convert this object so that I can use it in my chat model?

Tags: android, json, flutter, firebase, dart

I want to loop through the data received from Firebase Realtime Database and for each piece of data, pass it through my `ChatData` model. However, when I try to pass in `snapshot.value` it says that `The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?'.` How do I modify `snapshot.value` so that I can do this?

**The code:**

```
event.snapshot.children.forEach((snapshot) {
  _dataList.add(snapshot.value);
        
  msg = ChatData.fromJson(snapshot.value);
});
```

**ChatData model:**

```
ChatData.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic>? json): //Transform JSON into Message
  uid = json?['uid'] as String,
  text = json?['text'] as String,
  timestamp = DateTime.parse(json?['timestamp'] as String),
  type = json?['type'] as String,
  filterID = json?['filterID'] as String,
  mumbleURL = json?['mumbleURL'] as String;
```

What I don't understand is that in another version of this code, I simply added each piece of data from the snapshot into a `List` and then iterated over this list index by index and it worked just fine. Putting into a `List` first allowed me to pass in each element into `ChatData.fromJSON` just fine...

```
  event.snapshot.children.forEach((snapshot) {
    _dataList.add(snapshot.value);
  });

  _dataList.forEach((element) {
    msg = ChatData.fromJson(element); //This works just fine...why?
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ChatData Model like this.

```
ChatData.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot jsonMap) {
try {
uid = jsonMap.get('uid') != null ? jsonMap.get('uid').toString() : '';
text = jsonMap.get('text') != null ? jsonMap.get('text').toString() : '';
timestamp = DateTime.parse(jsonMap.get('timestamp').toString());
type = jsonMap.get('type') != null ? jsonMap.get('type').toString() : '';
filterID = jsonMap.get('filterID') != null ? jsonMap.get('filterID').toString() : '';
mumbleURL = jsonMap.get('mumbleURL') != null ? jsonMap.get('mumbleURL').toString() : '';
} catch (e) {
uid = '';
text = '';;
type = '';
print(e);
}
}
```

and getChats like this.

```
 Stream<List<ChatData>> getChats(Message message) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").doc(message.id).collection("chats").orderBy('time', descending: true).snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot query) {
      List<ChatData> retVal = [];
      query.docs.forEach((element) {
        retVal.add(Chat.fromDocumentSnapshot(element));
      });
      return retVal;
    });
  }
```

Hope you will get an idea from this.